# Крылатая латынь: Quad Licet Iovi, Non Licet Bovi, - как это правильно проговорить?

Tags: орфоэпия

Есть чудесный минутный мульт под названием ["Quad Licet Iovi, Non Licet Bovi"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIgwoLCZ9Uc), но хор голосов там так галдит, что я не расслышиваю нюансов...

> Quod licet Iovi (Jovi), non licet bovi (с лат. — «Что дозволено
>   Юпитеру, не дозволено быку») и «Quod licet bovi, non licet Iovi» —
>   «Что можно быку, нельзя Юпитеру».

["Квод лицэт йови, нон лицэт бови"](http://chtooznachaet.ru/perevod-i-obyasnenie-pogovorki-quod-licet-jovi-non-licet-bovi.html) - произношение (и написание) правильное? А то -

[голоса разделились](https://ru.forvo.com/word/licet/)... (Забавнее всех читает итальянец.)

---

[Как же писать верно: Jovi или Iovi?](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/97180407)

> В алфавите латыни классического периода не существовало букв J и U (на
>   самом деле, это не совсем верно, но объяснение нюансов написания
>   заняло бы слишком много места). Четкое разграничение ролей в парах
>   I-J и V-U произошло гораздо позднее, в эпоху Возрождения.
>
> Так что, если хотите придерживаться орфографии классической латыни,
>   пишите так: QVOD LICET IOVI NON LICET BOVI (ср. "Икар и мудрецы",
>   00:01:35) + пробелов между словами тоже не было, а в современной
>   орфографии - Quod licet Jovi non licet bovi...

О том же - ["Икар и мудрецы"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC2LeENSraM) (6 мин.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Латинский - мертвый язык, поэтому на фонетику внимания особо не обращают, в каждой стране своя латынь. Причина этого в том, что носителей языка не осталось, а в этом случае тоновое ударение, бывшее у римлян, исключает возможность точного воспроизведения в принципе.

За основу произношения как правило берут золотую латынь времён Цезаря и Цицерона, но в дальнейшем произношение менялось и возможны несколько вариантов произношения:

1. Пародия на реальное произношение римлян рубежа эр - **Qўо́дъ ли́цэт Їо́ўи, нон ли́цэт бо́ўи**. Где ў - читается как английская "W".
2. Золотая латынь в русском варианте - **кво́т ли́цэт Йо́ви, нон ли́цэт бови**.
3. Вульгарная латынь в русском варианте - **квот ли́кет Йо́ви, нон ли́кет бо́ви**.

Comment: Марк, а я призадумалась на рубежом эр... таким часом икс. ))) Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Но я читал, что ***"Квот мецет икс ови, нон мецет бови"***.
Значит, много вариантов произношения.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIgwoLCZ9Uc